# R: intersection of list components

Tags: r, list

In R, let `q` be a list with `100` components. Each component is a character vector:

```
i <-3
q[[i]] 
[1] "A" "B" "C" 
i <- 8
q[[i]]
[1] "B" "A" "D" "F"
```

and so on. 
I would like to intersect the components `q[[i]]`, for all `i`. 
As output I just need those characters which lie in the multiple intersection.
I only know the function

```
 intersect()
```

which works with 2 inputs and I don't really know `Reduce`.
Is there any smart-quick way to do this?

I thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just try this .

```
Reduce(intersect,q)
```

And If you want to show intermediate result:

```
Reduce(intersect,q,intermediate=TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer! A small question: I see no "q" in your code...should I use Reduce(intersect(q),ll)? I try with q=ll.